# SAMEORIGIN error using OOTB master page.

Tags: office-365, iframe, ootb, online

I'm using seattle.master with a theme on my O365 site collection. When I try to change to a different composed look on the subsites within that collection I'm getting console errors on the OOTB settings pages.

```
Refused to display 'https://portal.office.com/SuiteServiceProxy.aspx?exsvurl=1&realm=office365.com&Silent=1' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.

Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('https://portal.office.com') does not match the recipient window's origin ('null').
```

I understand the SAMEORIGIN concept but pointing to portal.office.com seems like it should be allowed by default because there are so many services that SP online calls back to. Is there a setting somewhere to allow this?